# how to get the conversion rate of a certain goal on google analytics?

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, quantitative-analysis

I would like to know the current conversion rate and the expected conversion rate to use them on tools like VWO or optimize by google

Answer (score 2):

This question feels off-topic according to the help center's guidelines: https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

For specific information on goals and how to track them, see the help topic about goals: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012040?hl=en

For overall Google Analytics training, I highly recommend Google Analytics Academy (https://analytics.google.com/analytics/academy/).

Comment: Thank you, and i didn't know that its off topic :) Thanks